# Can't assign proper filenames in bash loop using variable extension

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I'm stucked on this problem.
I'm using a loop to iterate commands on every file into a specific directory. While using the original names of files to generate new files, using variables extensions, it only works if variable has no text before. I've got this code:

```
for f in temp/temp_orfs/* ; do
    wc -l $f > ${f}_temp
    gawk '{print $1}' ${f}_temp > temp/temp_orfs/num_${f}_text
done

${f}_temp ---> exists
num_${f}_text --> doesn't exists
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f` contains the `temp/temp_orfs` prefix, not just the name of the file in the directory. Let's say that `f` expands to `temp/temp_orfs/foo`; then

- `${f}_temp` expands to `temp/temp_orfs/foo_temp`
- `temp/temp_orfs/num_${f}_text` expands to `temp/temp_orfs/num_temp/temp_orfs/foo_text`

---

You want the base name instead:

```
for f in temp/temp_orfs/*; do
    bf=${f##*/}
    wc -l "$bf" | gawk '{print $1}' > "temp/temp_orfs/num_${bf}_text"
done
```

Or, you can simply change directory first:

```
cd temp/temp_orfs
for f in *; do
    wc -l "$f" | gawk '{print $1}' > "temp/temp_orfs/num_${f}_text"
```

(Either way, the temporary file isn't necessary, but if you really want it, be sure to pay attention to what its name will be so you know where it gets created.)

---

`awk` probably isn't necessary. You can use input redirection to make `wc` output just a line count, although there may be a slight difference in how the result is formatted, depending on which implementation of `wc` you use:

```
# GNU wc
$ wc -l < some_some_file
21

# BSD wc
$ wc -l < some_small_file
      21
```

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful. So, in order to clarify: if the folder was just "temp/" instead of "temp/temp_orfs" , when defining the variable "$bf" , i just need to write   bf=${f#*/}  ?

Comment: `#` matches the shortest prefix; `##` the longest. Basically, you want to remove everything up to and including the last `/` in the path. (You can't match a particular number of components, so e.g. `${f###*/}` doesn't remove the first 3 directories.)

Comment: `wc -l "$f" | gawk '{print $1}'` = `wc -l < "$f"`

Comment: @EdMorton Conceptually, yes. Using `awk` trims the leading whitespace from the line count, though, so without knowing how `num_${f}_text` is used later, I wouldn't want to introduce a formatting change like this in the answer. (But whatever *does* use the file can almost certainly cope with that change with minimal adjustments.)

Comment: There's no leading or trailing white space in the output from `wc -l < file`. It's exactly the same as `wc -l file | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: @EdMorton GNU `wc` yes, BSD `wc` no. (The OP is likely using the GNU implementation, though.)

Comment: You're right, I've never noticed that difference before.